# Saving Kendo Grid sort to a database in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo Grid to display some client data.  The following code is what generates the grid.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var grid = $("#clientsDb").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                pageSize: 20,
                serverPaging: true
            },
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: true,
            scrollable: false
        }).data("kendoGrid");
        grid.table.kendoSortable({
            filter: ">tbody >tr",
            hint: $.noop,
            cursor: "move",
            placeholder: function(element) {
                return element.clone().addClass("k-state-hover").css("opacity", 0.65);
            },
            container: "#grid tbody",
            change: function(e) {
                var skip = grid.dataSource.skip(),
                    oldIndex = e.oldIndex + skip,
                    newIndex = e.newIndex + skip,
                    data = grid.dataSource.data(),
                    dataItem = grid.dataSource.getByUid(e.item.data("uid"));

                grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem);
                grid.dataSource.insert(newIndex, dataItem);
            }
        });
    });
```

The bottom half of the javascript code sorts the rows in the table.  I am having trouble figuring out how to save the sort to the database.  I assume I can post it to the DB using ajax, but I am unsure how that can be written.

Answer (score 0):

To store the row order you can add this in your change handler:

```
//Assuming ID uniquely identifies the row in your database 
$.post("@Url.Action("UpdateIndex")", { id: dataItem.ID, index:newIndex });
```

Server-side you will need to store the data against an Index/Order column.
Your grid can then be sorted on Index/Order column and will always reflect the changes made on the client side.

Comment: This works with the row sorting?  I guess I might not have mentioned that. The rows are being sorted not the columns.

Comment: Yes, it's passing the sorting column and direction (eg: ascending, descending).

Comment: Oh, I am dragging and dropping the rows. So it isn't necessarily ascending, descending

Comment: I see. I've changed my answer based on this new info. I hope it helps.